# Alternate fuel for motor cyce

Tags: fuel-system, performance, fuel-consumption

In some countries, Government mixes ethanol with petrol & diesel and distributes it to their consumers. This will save some of their imports. My question is

Can I blend petrol with Zatropha plant seed based oil and run my motor cycle?

If this technology can be possible, this also will help to reduce some percentage of imports of petrol and moreover Zatropha oil is available at cheaper cost, Zatropha plants are renewable and boost rural economy, if followed.

To try,What ratio of petrol and zatropha oil are to be mixed for running in a motorcycle?,What  modifications are necessary in the carburetor and spark plug?
What will be the effects when both fuels compared for pulling power, noise and smoke pollution, trouble free starting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are mixing other fuel , you need make changes in compression ratio and that will depends on the type and amount of the mixed fuel. Other wise your new fuel mixture will not be explode properly then it will emit more carbon and smoke.This will make two problems

- More polution- this may illeagl
- Ruin engine life- More carbon will cause more friction for piston and improper oiling, which will make your engine very old soon

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this isn't a daily driver, make sure it is legal locally to burn and start with small doses (2% mix) then add a little more every fill until it doesn't run properly. Then come back and tell us how it went! :) Also, this may foul plugs, ruin O2 sensors and lead to high carbon build-up, but all in the name of progress right?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you can't generally blend plant-based oils with petrol (gasoline for our US readers) and expect them to burn in the same way, although you can do so with Diesel. This is because petrol is a much lighter oil than Diesel, wheras plant oils, while lighter, are much closer to Diesel.

Ethanol is lighter still ( in fact, after methanol, is one of the shortest hydrocarbons possible... ), and so mixes well with either. To mix a plant oil with a light fuel, I believe you would have to ferment the plant matter first, then burn the resultant alcohol (i.e. ethanol) in the engine.

I await correction from those who know more chemistry than I...